# Got an error while build apk for react native expo app

Tags: react-native, build, expo, apk

I am new to react native development, in my app i am tried to scan a qr code code in my expo app everything works fine but if i try to build apk for react native expo app using ESA got an error. kindly provide the solution for this problem.

This is the error while build apk
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30
%.
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%
80%
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.0.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
- Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
- Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html
  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)".
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" ready.
> Installing NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" finished.
> Checking the license for package CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package CMake 3.22.1 accepted.
> Preparing "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)".
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" ready.
> Installing CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" complete.
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" finished.
> Configure project :expo
> Using expo modules

- expo-application (5.3.1)
- expo-barcode-scanner (12.5.3)
- expo-camera (13.4.4)
- expo-constants (14.4.2)
- expo-file-system (15.4.5)
- expo-font (11.4.0)
- expo-image-loader (4.3.0)
- expo-keep-awake (12.3.0)
- expo-local-authentication (13.4.1)
- expo-modules-core (1.5.12)
- expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.5.12)
- expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.5.12)
- expo-print (12.4.2)
- expo-sharing (11.5.0)
- expo-splash-screen (0.20.5)
  FAILURE:
  Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > The consumer was configured to find a component for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
> - generalReleaseRuntimeElements

- mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements
  All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Variant 'generalReleaseRuntimeElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
  - Unmatched attributes:
  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
  - Variant 'mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
- Unmatched attributes:
  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'mlkitRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
  The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
  - Variant 'generalDebugApiElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
  - Other compatible attribute:
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
  - Other compatible attribute:
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Variant 'generalReleaseApiElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime
  - Other compatible attribute:
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Variant 'mlkitDebugApiElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
  - Other compatible attribute:
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
  - Other compatible attribute:
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
  - Variant 'mlkitReleaseApiElements' capability StarGcc:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime
  - Other compatible attribute:
  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8hGi.png)
  This is my packege.json file
  {
  "name": "stargcc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
  "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
  "axios": "^1.6.2",
  "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
  "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
  "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
  "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
  "expo-local-authentication": "~13.4.1",
  "expo-print": "~12.4.2",
  "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
  "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.72.6",
  "react-native-animated-loader": "^1.0.0",
  "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
  "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
  "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
  "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
  "react-redux": "^9.0.2",
  "redux": "^5.0.0",
  "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
  "expo": "^49.0.21"
  },
  "engines": {
  "node": "18.18.0"
  },
  "private": true
  }